# How to set Fancybox size per link?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to have multiple links that will use Fancybox but I want to be able to set the width and height for the iframe popup.

Currently I have a link like this:

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://example.com" rel="example">
```

So is it possible to just have separate width/height for different links?

I've tried:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
autoSize: false,
width: 200,
height: 200 });
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps.

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="fancybox" data-width="200" data-height="200" rel="example">Click here"</a>

$(".fancybox").each(function(){
   var $a = $(this);
   var h = $a.data("height")
   var w = $a.data("width");
   $a.fancybox({
       'width' : w, 
       'height': h
   });
});
```

Comment: With that code, it doesn't work since the class is just "fancybox". It seems my link only works when it's "fancybox fancybox.iframe".

Comment: @Ironank The attributes should be `data-fancybox-width` and `data-fancybox-height` (fancybox v2.1.x) ... no need to use `.each()` but a regular fancybox initialization (neither requires the options `width` and `height` in the fancybox script)

Comment: Ah, ok got it now @jfk. This code DOES work, after scratching my head for hours I realized I had this javascript outside the fancybox initiliaze code!